# How to get values from a newly converted xml to json data structure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have created an app and I am currently converting the xml files to json, 
 but I need help looping through the data structure to get all the values for “media:thumbnail” . I
 have added the Json code below. If you could help me to extract the values I
 would be very grateful.

I have added a link to the Json file: http://pastebin.com/CCPem8Ge

iOS: ios 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [XMLReader](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader) which provides `NSDictionary` from `XML` file or data.

**Or** from `JSON` data get `NSDictionary` from `NSJSONSerialization`.

Now use that dictionary like this:

```
//get channel from main dictionary
NSDictionary *dictChannel = [dictXMLStructure objectForKey:@"channel"];  
//Check dictionary has object or not
if([dictChannel count]>0)
{
   //Get All items from channel dictionary
   NSArray *arrAllItems = [dictChannel objectForKey:@"item"];
   //Loop
   for(NSDictionary *dictItem in arrAllItems)
   {
      //Get thumbnail
      NSArray *arrAllImgs4Item = [dictItem objectForKey:@"media:thumbnail"];
      for(NSDictionary *dictInnerItem in arrAllImgs4Item)
      {
        //Use according to your requirement
        NSString *strURL = [dictInnerItem objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSLog(@"URL 4 Img : %@",strURL);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting back a null. I converted it to a NSDictionary like you said but I am still getting a null. Here is a link for the NSDictionary file: http://pastebin.com/s7EH8UFe, can you please check if I am missing something? @Prince